# Using If statement to check against 3 possibilities

Tags: swift, swift2

I am wanting to compare three randomly generated numbers to see if any two of them are equal.  I have an if statement that works but I would really like to combine the two else if statements into one if possible.  I am thinking there has to be some way to use *or* but its only a binary operator.  is there a way to use *?* and make a ternary argument in one else if  statement?

```
        if aRand == bRand && bRand == cRand{
            resultLabel.text = "3 out of 3"
        } else if
            (aRand == bRand || aRand == cRand) {
            resultLabel.text = "2 out of 3"
        } else if
        (bRand == cRand) {
        resultLabel.text = "2 out of 3"
        } else {
            resultLabel.text = "No Match"
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's

```
if aRand == bRand || aRand == cRand || bRand == cRand
```

Here a *swiftier* expression

```
let rand =  (aRand, bRand, cRand)
switch rand {
  case let (a, b, c) where a == b && b == c : resultLabel.text = "3 out of 3"
  case let (a, b, c) where a == b || a == c || b == c : resultLabel.text = "2 out of 3"
  default : resultLabel.text = "No match"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, if aRand == bRand || aRand == cRand || bRand == cRand is what I needed.  I feel like this was too easy and I appreciate the responses.  I am positive I tried this and it didn't work originally but I tried it again and this time it did.

Comment: I like the swiftier expression too, It seems much more adaptable to expansion. I am going to try that out and see where I can go with it.  Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

Shorter way:

```
if (aRand == bRand && bRand == cRand) {

    resultLabel.text = "3 out of 3"

} else if (aRand == bRand || bRand == cRand || aRand == cRand) {

    resultLabel.text = "2 out of 3"

} else {

    resultLabel.text = "No Match"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your algorithm correctly, you can avoid `if` altogether:

```
let aRand = 0
let bRand = 1
let cRand = 1

let allValues = [aRand, bRand, cRand]
let uniqueValues = Set(allValues)

let text: String

if (uniqueValues.count == allValues.count) {
    text = "No match"
} else {
    text = String(format: "%i out of %i", allValues.count - uniqueValues.count + 1, allValues.count)
}

print(text)
```

This will work for *any* number of values.